# How do I submit separate rows in my MySQL Database for every line break I make in a text area form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a text area form were someone can enter multiple links that are separated by line breaks and each link goes into its own row under the link table in my database. I can't seem to figure it out. I've looked everywhere.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            <textarea action="results.php" id="textarea" name="url" class="boxsizingBorder">
            </textarea>
            <br />
            <textarea id="results" name="conversion" class="boxsizingBorder"></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Records" id="convert" onclick="getTrackData()">
            <span id="counter"></span>
        </form>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include('db.php');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons");

    // Escape user inputs for security

    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $array = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $url);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO persons (url) VALUES ('$url')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**This is how it looks:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilofh.png

**This is how I want it to look:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UXQ3.png

**EDIT:** I made the changes to the mysql API, but still can't seem to figure out how to get each link in its own row.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
    include('db.php');


    // Escape user inputs for security

    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $array = explode('\n', $url);

    // attempt insert query execution
    foreach($array as $url) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO persons (url) VALUES ('$url')");
        // close connection
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Anyway, you can try a `foreach` on `nl2br`, see if that works. Might even have to use `explode/implode`.

Comment: By the way, you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions that do not intermix with each other. Use **one** and only one.

Comment: *"EDIT: I made the changes to the mysql API"* - Edit your question with the code you're using now.

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons");` you're mixing again and should read as `$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM persons");` but it's unclear as to what your DB connection really is, because you're using `$con` in another part of your codes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using preg_split, you can simply use `explode()` on new lines.

```
$array = explode('\n', $url);
```

Then you can just use a foreach on it to perform the insert.

```
foreach($array as $url)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO persons (url) VALUES ('$url')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
```

But keep in mind this also depends on how you observe new lines. There are WYSIWYG editors out there that will convert new lines into `<br/>` tags. Make sure you test to ensure that's not your case.

**Edit**

Fred made a great point. You can't mix the mysql API's, you need to choose one. As the `mysql_` library is deprecated, it's best to use the `mysqli_` library.

You need to change your connector function to `mysqli_connect()` instead of `mysql_connect()` and make appropriate changes from there.

Comment: There's just one small problem; OP is mixing APIs.

Comment: It still puts all the links in one row.